# Composite Control/Flyout Menu Customization

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to customize the Composite Control/Flyout Menu (Address Field) in crm 2013 form.Is there any way to add new fields to the control or remove fields from it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately any available Composite control has limited possibilities for customization. It's not possible to add fields inside or remove fields from it. What you really can do is to hide field inside using JavaScript or Business Rule - https://dipankarbhattacharya.com/2014/03/31/how-can-we-customize-the-address-composite-control/

Also it is possible to change requirement level of a field inside using again JavaScript or Business Rule.